# Using Conditionals in Post Build Script in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I am trying to use a conditional "if" in a post build script based on the current build configuration. The script is exiting with code 255. Here are the parameters:

> Configuration: Example Release (there is a space between the two
>   words)
>
> Post-Build Script: if $(ConfigurationName) == Example Release copy
>   "XXX" "YYY"

I am assuming there's an issue with the configuration name being 2 words instead of one. I tried putting "" around the $(ConfigurationName), but that gave the same result.

Comment: I think you need more quotes. Like this: `if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Example Release" copy ...`

Comment: If this won't work, prepend the whole line with `echo `, this won't copy anything but you'll see the exact command line the IDE is trying to execute, with these VS-defined variables expanded.